# Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined react

Tags: reactjs

I already searched for solutions and found many but they don't fit my problem.so I don't know how to solve this problem.

this is full error:-

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `WithAuthentication`.

and this is `withAuthentication.js` file

```
import React from 'react'

import AuthUserContext from './context'
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase'

const withAuthentication = (Component) => {
    class WithAuthentication extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)    
            this.state = {
                authUser: null,
            }
        }
            componentDidMount() {
            this.listener = this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
                (authUser) => {
                    authUser
                        ? this.setState({ authUser })
                        : this.setState({ authUser: null })
                }
            )
        }    
        componentWillUnmount() {
            this.listener()
        }
            render() {
            return (
                <AuthUserContext.Provider value={this.state.authUser}>
                    <Component {...this.props} />
                </AuthUserContext.Provider>
            )
        }
    }    
    return withFirebase(WithAuthentication)
}    
export default withAuthentication
```

Comment: Component started with Capital Letter are considered the react based custom user components while Component starting with lowercase letter are considered as the builtin Dom components like heading tag, div tag etc.

Comment: Secondly, don't use class based component directly inside functional component instead create a separate component say ABC and then import it inside functional component

Comment: Check all your imports.  Is AuthUserContext a default export?  That would be my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing `extend Component` to `extend React.Component`